# Animating a simple graphic correctly in PIXI.js

Tags: javascript, animation, pixi.js

I have a graphic in PIXI and I would like to simply expand it to the left by a flowing transition. Researching the official docs, I didn't really find any best practices or what to do here.

My code currently looks like this

```
var bar = new PIXI.Graphics();
bar.beginFill(color);
bar.lineStyle(1, 0x000000, 10);
bar.drawRect(
  my_x,
  my_y * line,
  bar_width,
  bar_height
);
```

and shows the bar correctly in the final shape. My question now would be how to slowly expand it from 0.

I tried giving the bar a new position via `bar.length = final_pos` but it instantly changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my answer to similar question about animating primitives / shapes in Pixi.js: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60515362/3174731 . There i showed how to animate a polygon (`drawPolygon` method) - but similarily you can do it with rectangle (`drawRect`).

The main idea is to do following on each iteration of "main loop":

1. Create shape with desired parameters (position, positions of vertices, size, color etc).
2. Add this shape to your stage (directly to stage or to some container which is in stage).
3. Render stage.
4. Remove this shape from stage (or from container - if was added to some other container).

   - this should also allow Garbage Collector to clean this object from memory - so the memory will not fill after some time of this loop running.
5. Change some parameters so on next iteration it will be created slightly different in point 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry for commenting that late. As I have a lot of shapes that need to be adjusted like that, I don't think that adding each one of them to the main loop and iterating is a good idea for now...

Comment: @creyD have you tried it? :) Keep in mind that Pixi.js is using WebGL (so hardware acceleration) - which should mitigate your performance concerns.

Comment: Just try it and Im sure it would work for you.  Js can can iterate through THOUSANDS!!!! of things a frame, hell even draw thousands.  If your to lazy to write the animation code then use something like anim.js, been looking at that lately and it could do the nice transitions for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will add my code in a separate answer below, I actually did it slightly different, but your answer and your comments helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @domis86 and @PAEz I tried to implement it and refined it a little bit to the following code. I used a mask, but it should work with adjusting the width directly too.

```js
var mask_width = 0;
var loading_bar = setInterval(function () {
  if (mask_width < bar_width) {
    var this_mask = new PIXI.Graphics();
    this_mask.beginFill(0xff3300);
    this_mask.drawRect(my_x, my_y * line, bar_width, bar_height);
    this_mask.endFill();
    bar.mask = this_mask;
    mask_width += 1;
  } else {
    bar.mask = null;
    clearInterval(loading_bar);
  }
}, 10);
```

This code applies a new mask with slightly increased coverage every 10ms until it reaches the complete width.

Comment: So you are creating new "shape" anyway because `this_mask` is a `PIXI.Graphics` (`var this_mask = new PIXI.Graphics();` ) :)

Comment: Yes I did that, but I didn't use the global game loop to iterate the variables, which was important for me, as the code is pretty complex...