# Smoothly animating a progress bar in PixiJS

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I have a progress bar that will increase as my program completes but it jumps from increment a to b rather than smoothly easing in or out. Is there a way I can tween the progress bar rather than having it jerk?
The progress bar currently is just a PIXI.graphic object in a container that changes positions.

```js
 let progressBarContainer = new PIXI.Container();
 let progressBar = new PIXI.Graphics();
 progressBarContainer.addChild(progressBar);

 //after progress is made

 progressBar.position = (x + progress, y)
```

I was thinking of having a timer function that increases the progress bar by some x value until it reaches the desired percentage (maybe use a cubic function to imitate easing animations) but I was wondering if maybe there is a more effective way that I have not come across yet.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe see example (codepen) from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60515362/3174731 and try to create something similar?